# Vector Highlight Functionality is not working for Beider Morse Analyser in Lucene?

Tags: lucene.net

Vector Highlight functionality is not working properly when we use beider Morse Analyzer in lucene.NET. Anybody came across this issue?

Vector highlight is working fine for standard analyzer but it is not working properly for Beider morse. It is highlighting the entire string.

```
Directory directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory("LuceneIndex");
Analyzer analyzer = Analyzer.NewAnonymous(createComponents: (fieldName, reader) =>
            {

                var tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(input: reader);
                PhoneticEngine phoneticEngine = new PhoneticEngine(NameType.GENERIC, RuleType.APPROX, false);
                var stream = new BeiderMorseFilter(input: tokenizer, phoneticEngine);
                return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, stream);
            });
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer);
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("id", i.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("EmployeeName", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
writer.Optimize();
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "EmployeeName", mAnalyzer);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
int results = hits.Length();
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} results", results);
for (int i = 0; i < results; i++)
{

    SimpleHTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter();
                Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(htmlFormatter, new QueryScorer(queryParser));
                int totalScoreDocs = tTopDocs.ScoreDocs.Length > 30 ? 30 : tTopDocs.ScoreDocs.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < totalScoreDocs; i++)
                {
                    int id = tTopDocs.ScoreDocs[i].Doc;
                    Document doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                    string text = doc.Get("EmployeeName");
                    TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.GetAnyTokenStream(mIndexSearcher.IndexReader, id, "EmployeeName", analyzer);
                    TextFragment[] frag = highlighter.GetBestTextFragments(
                   tokenStream, text, mergeContiguousFragments: false, maxNumFragments: 10);  // highlighter.GetBestFragments(tokenStream, text, 3, "...");
                    for (int j = 0; j < frag.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (frag[j] != null && frag[j].Score > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(frag[j].ToString());
                        }
                    }
}
Sample For Lucene highlight
With Standard analyzer;
Input-John
Output-William <B>John<B> Russel

With Beider Morse analyzer;
Input-John
Output-<B>William John Russel<B>
```

Comment: Not aware of it.  Which version of LuceneNET?  Also, please provide example of failing code with information how it is failing.

Comment: @RonC Hi Ron updated the Code with the Question

Comment: @RonC Lucene Dotnet 4.8.0 pre release

Comment: I now understand the issue.  Can you provide a small set of working code that can produce the two outputs you show.  The code provided is missing several pieces such that it won't compile if placed inside a unit test.

Comment: @RonC Hi Ron could not able to provide the exact due to security reasons.provided similar code which u can run on console app.